# How to get AUTHORIZATION header value?

Tags: php

I am trying to obtain a Bearer Token from a custom API I am developing. When I am requesting my API, I am setting this header information with this info:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwkyz'
```

I can view my requested headers through Chrome and it shows me:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-CA;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
Authorization: Bearer 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwkyz
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: api.localhost.dev
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36
```

However, when I try and get the header value for through the `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` or `$_SERVER['Authorization']` variable, there is no information.

EDIT:

I have also tried adding these to my `.htaccess` with no luck, either:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

And

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And

```
CGIPassAuth On
```

Here is a quick rundown of my server set-up:

```
PHP 7.3.11 CGI/FastCGI
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Linux 4.9.159-vs2.3.9.8-vs+ x86_64
```

Is there a different way I can get the `'Authorization': 'Bearer 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwkyz'` that is being sent through the header?

Comment: Are you actually using `$SERVER` or the correct `$_SERVER` ?

Comment: @apokryfos - good catch, I am using `$_SERVER`, I just did not type that correctly in my original question.

Comment: Strangely enough, when I use `phpinfo();`, I see a `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` and `$_ENV['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` in my PHP Variables.

Comment: @zeropsi did you ever figure this out? Or find a work around?

Comment: @arecaps - the only way I was able to make it work was to make sure that I had allowed the Authorization header in my response: `$response->setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, Origin");`

Answer (score 7):

Check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

> Returns: An associative array of all the HTTP headers in the current request, or FALSE on failure.

With `getallheaders()`, you can retrieve the request headers, and access them via an associative array:

```
<?php

$headers = getallheaders();

if (in_array('Authorization', $headers)) {
    echo $headers['Authorization'];
}
```

You can also add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

This should then make the following available for you:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
```

Comment: These are the headers that are returned: 
  `"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-CA;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "Referer": "http:\/\/localhost:8100",
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
  "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
  "Origin": "http:\/\/localhost:8100",
  "Content-Type": "application\/json",
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/81.0.4044.129 Safari\/537.36",
  "Accept": "application\/json",
  "Connection": "close",
  "Host": "api.localhost.dev"`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either. I have tried a few `.htaccess` methods with no success. I updated my original questions with some additional details on what I have tried and my environment set-up.